# Force creating Lazy<T> objects

Tags: c#, lazy-loading, lazy-initialization

I'm being given a collection of [`Lazy<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.lazy-1) items. I then want to forcibly 'create' them all in one go.

```
void Test(IEnumerable<Lazy<MailMessage>> items){
}
```

Normally with a `Lazy<T>` item, the contained object won't be created until one of it's member's is accessed.

Seeing as there is no `ForceCreate()` method (or similar), I am forced to do the following:

```
var createdItems = items
    .Where(a => a.Value != null && a.Value.ToString() != null)
    .Select(a => a.Value);
```

Which is using `ToString()` to force created each item.

Is there a neater way to forcibly create all items?

Comment: If you just want to forcibly create `Lazy<T>` instances, without doing something with them, then your approach is definitely wrong. On the other hand, if you going to access `Lazy<T>` members, then you don't need to create them in special way.

Comment: You don't need to access a member of the lazily created object, accessing Lazy.Value is enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need two things to create all the lazy items, you need to enumerate all items (but not necessarily keep them), and you need to use the `Value` property to cause the item to be created.

```
items.All(x => x.Value != null);
```

The `All` method needs to look at all values to determine the result, so that will cause all items to be enumerated (whatever the actual type of the collection might be), and using the `Value` property on each item will cause it to create its object. (The `!= null` part is just to make a value that the `All` method is comfortable with.)

Comment: I like your approach, it initializes the values without creating a list. Depending on what the OP wants, this might be a better solution.

Comment: Note that if the `.Value` of any of the Lazy items is `null`, then subsequent items in the enumerable may not have `.Value` called on them, as `All()` can short-circuit when it sees the first `false`.

Comment: Not only can `All()` short-circuit but Linq operations are lazy, and this code may never access *any* of the `.Value` properties.  The Select...ToList solution should be accepted instead.

Answer (score 7):

To get the list of all the lazily initialized values:

```
var created = items.Select(c => c.Value).ToList();
```

Comment: That will just create an enumerator that can loop through the items, it won't actually loop through anything.

Comment: No, accessing [`Value`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642177.aspx) is engough

Comment: @Guffa You can add `ToList()`

Comment: I fixed it and added `ToList()` to actually get the lazily initialized values

Comment: This will allocate O(n) memory, just use `foreach (var x in items) _ = x.Value;`

Answer (score 2):

```csharp
foreach (var x in lazyItems)
{
    _ = x.Value;
}
```

Advantages over some of the other solutions include that this solution:

- Does not do an extra allocation of O(n) memory / create an output collection.
- A null Value does not cause instantiation to stop.
- Avoids possible confusion about whether LINQ deferred execution meant the instantiation never actually occurred.

Answer (score 1):

> Seeing as there is no ForceCreate() method (or similar)

You can always create a `ForceCreate()` extension method on `Lazy<T>` for this:

```
public static class LazyExtensions
{
    public static Lazy<T> ForceCreate<T>(this Lazy<T> lazy)
    {
        if (lazy == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(lazy));

        _ = lazy.Value;
        return lazy;
    }
}
```

...accompanied by a `ForEach` extension method on `IEnumerable<T>`:

```
public static class EnumerableExtensions
{
    public static void ForEach<T>(this IEnumerable<T> enumerable, Action<T> action)
    {
        if (enumerable == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(enumerable));
        if (action == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(action));            

        foreach (var item in enumerable)
        {
            action(item);
        }
    }
}
```

By combining these two extension methods you can then forcibly create them all in one go:

```
items.ForEach(x => x.ForceCreate());
```